# Handling application settings in Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, settings

I'm working on refactoring an old web application.

In this new version I'm using Spring 3.x and I'd like to rethink the whole part of application settings. In the old application I used a custom approach using a DB table and a dedicated DAO.

I need to change system settings at runtime, so I think `properties` files are not the right choiche. I'm also considering `java.util.prefs` API.

Can you suggest a common approach to this issue? Is there some utility in Spring to address this problem?

Comment: Have you considered JMX Beans?

Comment: Have you considered uding JNDI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided that the best solution for me is to use [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) API and to store app settings in DB, using [`DatabaseConfiguration`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/DatabaseConfiguration.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue time ago. My final approach was use the Property place holder of Spring, but loading this object from database instead from a property file.
http://pure-essence.net/2011/02/10/spring-loading-properties-from-database-with-a-twist/

The only problem is, if you want to change on runtime of the application, you need to refresh the ApplicationContext, which can be a little tricky.

```
            ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("Application-  context.xml");

            // Your application code here

         ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)ctx).refresh();
```